# Which ODBC driver (x86/x64) for php 7.2 - xampp?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, x86, odbc

I am trying clone to localhost project based on MS SQL. After the first page view, I get an error: `not found driver` so I downloaded [Microsoft Drivers 5.6 for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57916) after that I get an exception:

> SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x86: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

so after some anchor clicks, I was here [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server® - Windows, Linux, & macOS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567) and there I was choosing for the x86 version.

But if I want to install it, I get the error: `not supported operating system`

You say - so just install x64... But 3 days I can't resolve this issue on mssql [SQL Server + Eloquent conversion datetime in query/results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477782/sql-server-eloquent-conversion-datetime-in-query-results) and now I clone the whole project on another pc and I hope it will work...

So is here somebody who know? Is important have x86 ODBC version? Is there possibility install it some manual way?

ADITIONAL INFO:

- OS: Win 7 64bit
- PHP: 7.2
- SQLSRV DRIVER: php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll and php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: i was updated question. (win7 x64)

Comment: Did you try ODBC driver version 13?

Comment: Yes. Same error: `not supported operating system` problem is x86 driver on x64 system.